# Skip frames in rendering

Tags: rendering, keyframes, timeline

This might sound weird. I have a scene with alembic files. There are chunks in the timeline which do not need to be rendered. For example in a 200 frames timeline I want to skip say 20-51 and then 110-167. I cannot do this manually as I will be leaving my PC to render overnight and to save the render time I do not want to render the redundant parts. Is there a way to setup the file so that I render the parts I want from the timeline?

Answer (score 11):

This addon called [Loom](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom) is exactly what you need.

It allows you to specify ranges and specific frames that you want to render or skip. It's even possible to render every n*th* frame.

> The addon allows to render single frames, multiple **frame ranges** as well as subframes, either directly within Blender's UI (as usual) or in a new terminal instance as background process in case you want to continue working while rendering.

From: [How to render specific frames of animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114376/31447)

Comment: This will be a better answer if it includes a description of what Loom is and what it does.

Comment: Good point. I've added a short description.

Comment: @RichSedman Funny that this one-liner, now even has reached the same number of up-votes as the original answer by the author.

Comment: FTR: I hadn't seen that other answer before. I've been using the addon for years. Also funny that this answer got more up-votes than my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214658/more-time-is-spent-on-render-preparation-than-on-the-actual-rendering-what-can/214690#214690) ;)

Comment: This is life changing. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Sure thing. Please don't forget to mark as solved ;)

Answer (score 2):

One workaround could be to animate the collection/scene visibility so in the frames you don't need the render, you set up everything to be *not* rendered (you'll get black images).

You'll have a very quick render for empty black frames.

Here's a reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260936

Comment: Thats a very good idea. In case there is no legitimate solution this would be the best work around

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a few for loops if you're familiar with that as shown here: [Python Render Specific Frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/python-render-specific-frames)